# How to make launch activity always as home activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have 3 activities in my app. A is the launcher activity, when I press on a button Activity B will be started, then I have a button to start Activity A or I can press back button and I can go to A. On back press previous values retained in and on button click new values will be set on A.

When I click a button in B , A will be started, I am using **REORDER TO FRONT** flag and singletop as launch mode. New activity is not getting created . When I press back button on A it will transit to B and again I press back button app exits. I want to have activity A on back press on B. I cannot do  anything in `onBackpressed()` in B as B is used in several scenarios apart from the above mentioned scenario. How to manage it.

Comment: if you have activity A on back press of B, the user may end in an infinite loop A-B-A-B... So it is better to avoid such scenarios.

Comment: why you want to restart activity A? Can't you move your initialization part to onResume()? That way when you are coming back to A when you pressed button in activity B you can initialize with new values. You will just need to pass the new values from B.

Comment: @Rajeev That I can do. My problem is I want A as home activity , wherever we go and when we press back button last activity should be A.

Comment: If you do not want activity A to die when you press back button in A to go to B, then you will have consume the back key press in activity A. B anyway will be killed when you press back button in B. But A will always be present there. But when you finally want to exit the app, then you need to have the default implementation (which is to kill the activity) for back press. So both the statements contradict each other. Not sure what you can do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have nor clearly understood what you are trying to do, but you could try the up-navigation pattern (http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back).

You would have to declare in your manifest that activity A is the parent activity of B and then use `NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);` in your button OnClickListener.
(NavUtils is in the support.v4 package).